# Spring AOP - How to prevent derived classes from being targeted

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I have a base class with several derived classes that extend it.
I want to restrict my Spring AOP Aspect to the superclass only, so that the AOP Proxy would be created for it only and not for the derived classes.

I tried to define the pointcut as follows:

```
@Pointcut("execution(* com.blah.platform.persistence.generic.GenericDaoImpl.*(..))")
public void withinGenericDao() {}
```

where GenericDaoImpl is the superclass.

I still can see that proxies are generated for the derived classes as well:

```
2011-11-24 18:00:28,616 ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]] DEBUG [JdkDynamicAopProxy] Creating JDK dynamic proxy: target source is SingletonTargetSource for target object [com.blah.admin.persistence.impl.CircuitDAOImpl@5c81cf46]
2011-11-24 18:00:28,638 ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]] DEBUG [JdkDynamicAopProxy] Creating JDK dynamic proxy: target source is SingletonTargetSource for target object [com.blah.admin.persistence.impl.CategoryDAOImpl@55eef3c1]
2011-11-24 18:00:28,645 ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]] DEBUG [JdkDynamicAopProxy] Creating JDK dynamic proxy: target source is SingletonTargetSource for target object [com.blah.admin.services.circuit.impl.CircuitsServiceImpl@d50112d]
2011-11-24 18:00:28,953 ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]] DEBUG [JdkDynamicAopProxy] Creating JDK dynamic proxy: target source is SingletonTargetSource for target object [com.blah.events.persistence.impl.EventsDAOImpl@4222023a]
2011-11-24 18:00:29,030 ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]] DEBUG [JdkDynamicAopProxy] Creating JDK dynamic proxy: target source is SingletonTargetSource for target object [com.blah.events.persistence.impl.PrototypesDAOImpl@d3bef50]
```

I would think that this should only happen when the pointcut is defined as follows:

```
execution(public * com.mycompany.myservice.MyService+.*(..))
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you change your `PointCut` definition from `execution` to `within`? I have had success with that in the past. (Note that the syntax is a little different. See the Spring AOP reference documentation for details.)

e.g. `@PointCut("within(com.blah.platform.persistence.generic.GenericDaoImpl)")`

Answer (score 0):

A subclass inherits public methods and properties of the parent class, include your annotations.